# Get parent page's hidden variable data in child iframe

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe

I have a web page inside which i have put an iframe.
The iframe loads a pdf file after making few calculations.
The calculations are carried out from server side code based on parameters which are stored in a hidden variable in the parent page.

this is the parent page html markup

```
    <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="iPdf"></iframe>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnPrintRo" name="hdnPrintRo" value="1" />
```

The src of the iframe is set dynamically.

```
 $('#iPreRoPDf').attr('src', "PrintPDF.aspx?printid=" + printGuid);
```

This is how i try to access the hidden field from the page which is loaded in iframe(PrintPDF.aspx)

```
string a = Request.Form["hdnField"];
```

But i get null everytime.

How shall i get value of hidden field?
Or shall i change the way i m fetching the value at server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript

Comment: Take a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1450286/1341692)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass hidden field values as a query string in your iframe source URL.

```
$('#iPreRoPDf').attr('src', "PrintPDF.aspx?printid=" + printGuid + "&PrintRo=" + $('#hdnPrintRo').val());
```

As discuss with questioner:

Please try below Javascript to get hidden field value in `PrintPDF.aspx` page.

```
var getHdnFld = parent.document.getElementById('hdnPrintRo').value;
```

Comment: Thanks Dexterity, but cant do this. As the hidden variable will have a json string which stores 100's of parameters.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please try that logic in your `PrintPDF.aspx` page