# get value of parent window in modal from page opened in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that is opened in iframe, that page has a modal/popup in it. I want to access the parent page (opened in iframe) values,  in modal using jquery or javascript. any ideas how could I do that?

I have tried it using window.parent.document but it takes me to the index page, while I want to remain inside the body of page opened in iframe. And window.parent.$('#someId:checked') gives me [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access elements of parent window from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027799/access-elements-of-parent-window-from-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access parent iframe elements from a child javascript page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450286/how-to-access-parent-iframe-elements-from-a-child-javascript-page)

Comment: @YuPPie I have tried that method but it didn't work. it takes me to the index/parent page while i want to remain in the body of page opened in iframe

Comment: @caramba i tried it but it didin't work

Comment: As you are just accessing the value, how will it takes to some other page. Give us a code snippet @UmerFarooq